# I am getting 502 always in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Hello I am writing a application which I want to run in GKE and here is my deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: chopcast-dev
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: chopcast-dev
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: chopcast-dev
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: chopcast-dev
        image: eu.gcr.io/valued-amp-998877/chopcast:latest
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /api/v1/healthz
            port: 5000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /api/v1/healthz
            port: 5000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

Here is the service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: chopcast-dev-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: chopcast-dev
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

and here is the ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: chopcast-dev-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: gke-tribetacttics-static-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: chopcast-dev-certificate
    #kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: "chopcast-dev-service"
    servicePort: 5000
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: "chopcast-dev-service"
          servicePort: 5000
    host: "gke.abcd.com"
```

every time I get my service running successfully and when I run the exposed service with the assigned IP it works file ie

`x.x.x.x:5000/api/v1/healthz`

But whenever I put the ingress static IP I always get

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

I tried with BackendConfig too.
As per the documentation, the health should pick up from the readinessProbe but it seems it is not picking up as I can see in load balancer section it is 0/1 backend is up. Unfortunately, I don't want to serve 200 on the / route.

Please help.

Comment: Hello. I ran your `YAML` definitions with `gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0` and everything seemed okay. Could you check if your pods are in `Ready` state? Can you run example pod and check if you can get the `200` response from your `chopcast-dev` pods?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out what was going wrong. The readinessProbe path should have a trailing slash as my application is designed that way.

```
      readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /api/v1/healthz/
            port: 5000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10
```

Here are few checklist

1. Check your application name, namespace and labels.
2. Use selectors and check all selectors are proper.
3. Use trailing slashes if your app router is designed such way.
4. Also check the container port in your deployment YAML.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Which version of kubernetes are you using?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: chopcast-dev-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "gke.abcd.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: chopcast-dev-service
            port:
              number: 5000
```

Comment: not sure. now trying apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

Comment: 1.15.12-gke.20 this is which I got from cluster-info. are you asking this version?

Comment: What do you mean by basic settings?

Comment: Why don't you try with basic settings like: `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: chopcast-dev-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: gke.abcd.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gke.abcd.com
          servicePort: 5000`

Comment: Hope you tried with the right `serviceName: chopcast-dev-service`?

Comment: yes, currently I am using everything with same name chopcast-dev but still, I am going crazy with this error.